# Set Container to vertical columns instead of rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been given the task of editing a friends' website. I have very limitted HTML/CSS knowledge.

Can you please tell me how to display the ffg code vertically (in columns) instead of in rows.

sample is code from the editor :

```
 <div class="content-section-a">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="column">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
                <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h2 class="section-heading">Member of the<br>Smartrac Group</h2>
                <p class="lead">Smartrac is a national consulting firm that provides creative and sustainable solutions to challenges facing the modern business</p>
            </div>
           <!-- <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ipad.png" alt="">
            </div>-->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.content-section-a -->

<div class="content-section-b">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="column">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-push-6  col-sm-6">
                <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h2 class="section-heading">Compliance in terms of :<br>Consumer Protection Act</h2>
                <p class="lead">All suppliers of goods and services will need to take note of the new measures and ensure that they are able to comply with the Act's requirements. Let us help you realise that.</p>
            </div>
             <!--<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-pull-6  col-sm-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/dog.png" alt="">
            </div>-->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
```

This appears as a row going acrosswith the text and a placeholder for a pic which the client doesnt want anymore, which i have commented out.

how do i display the text only but next to each other vertically in eg columns  on one line and not seperately

Comment: Sounds like your friend picked the right person for html/CSS help. Judging by what you have, you really can't make then into vertical columns as is. To do it correctly, you would need to modify the html.

Comment: This non-standard Bootstrap markup (the are nested column elements and no row elements). It needs to be modified to follow standards. You'll need to use row nesting to get a columnar layout. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: Also, what does "ffg" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put your two blocks in a row and remove the `col-lg-offset-1` and the `col-sm-push-6` :

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading">Member of the<br>Smartrac Group</h2>
            <p class="lead">Smartrac is a national consulting firm that provides creative and sustainable solutions to challenges facing the modern business</p>
        </div>
           <div class="col-lg-5  col-sm-6">
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading">Compliance in terms of :<br>Consumer Protection Act</h2>
            <p class="lead">All suppliers of goods and services will need to take note of the new measures and ensure that they are able to comply with the Act's requirements. Let us help you realise that.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Thanks MatthieuLemoine.